# Doing an Highscore table

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to create a Highscore table for my Arcade spaceshooter game, im doing this table with variables so no DB is needed to store the scores they will be temporary

```c#
var high1 : int;
var high2 : int;
var high3 : int;
var high4 : int;
var high5 : int;

function OnGUI () {
    var camera;
    camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");
    var scorepoints;
    scorepoints = camera.GetComponent(Scorescript).currentScore;
}
```

I'm using Unity btw and im trying to access the Scorescript which harbors the current score the Player had, problem is it always says it cant find the component of the script,the object tag name is right and the script name too, here is the score script:

```c#
var customSkin : GUISkin;

var enemy;
enemy = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy");

var currentScore : int = 0;
var visibleScore : int = 0;

function OnGUI () {
    GUI.skin = customSkin;
    GUILayout.BeginArea ( Rect ( Screen.width / 1.2, Screen.height / 10 ,300,200) );
    GUILayout.Box ( visibleScore.ToString () );
    GUILayout.EndArea ();
}

function AnimateVisibleScore () {
    iTween.ValueTo (
        gameObject,
        {
            "from" : visibleScore,
            "to" : currentScore,
            "onupdate" : "ChangeVisibleScore",
            "time" : 0.5
        }
    );
}

function ChangeVisibleScore ( i : int ) {
    visibleScore = i;
}

function IncrementScore ( i : int ) {
    currentScore += i;
    AnimateVisibleScore ();
}

function DecrementScore ( i : int ) {
    currentScore -= i;
    AnimateVisibleScore ();
}
```

And I'm a nublet at scripting if anyone could give a hand in finishing this particular part i would be very grateful.

Comment: Just as a tip, instead of separate score variables score1, score2 etc, use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```c#
scorepoints = Camera.main.GetComponentInChildren("Scorescript");
```